# Define a matrix square root that preserves regularity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

Let $A:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. Is it possible to define $C:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ satisfying the following two properties:

1. for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $C_tC_t^\top=A_tA^\top_t+BB^\top$,
2. if $A$ is   Lipschitz in $t$, i.e., $|A_t-A_s|\le L|t-s|$ for all $t,s$, then $C$ is also Lipschitz in $t$.

---

The answer is affirmative for one-dimensional case, as one can simply define
$C_t=\sqrt{A^2_t+B^2}$. Then one can easily verify that if $A$ is Lipschitz continuous, then $C$ is Lipschitz continuous regardless of $B=0$ or not.

The question is more challenging in a  multidimensional  setting, as $BB^\top$ has zero eigenvalue is not equivalent to $BB^\top =0$.
It is not clear to me how to establish Item 2. I am happy to impose a boundedness condition on $A$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $$C_t=\sqrt{A_tA^\top_t+BB^\top}$$ as the [positive square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) of the positive definite matrix $A_tA^\top_t+BB^\top$.

You can find more discussions on related results searching for "[\(BB^\top\)  positive square root](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28BB%5E%5Ctop%5C%29%20%20positive%20square%20root%20)" on SearchOnMath, like this "[Fractional power of self adjoint operators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898177/fractional-power-of-self-adjoint-operators.#answer-1898209)".

Comment: Could you explain why this definition $C_t$ preserves the Lipschitz continuity of $A_t$, item2?